# My debugger appears to be running different code than what I'm building

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, writing in C++.  In my program, I have a .dll that contains the a bunch of functions that I use frequently in my program. Recently, I've been having quite a bit of trouble with changing the .dll.  Whenever I change the functions that are defined in my DLL, when the program builds and runs, the changes don't seem to take effect.  That is to say, I believe my DLL is not properly updating each time I successfully build (or rebuild) my solution.

If I try to set a breakpoint in any of the functions in the .cpp file (the one that gets hidden from the user in place of a DLL), visual studio tells me the code will not be executed and that a breakpoint cannot be set there.  However, earlier today I could set a breakpoint there.

Also, one of my functions prints "Frame Received" to the debug output in visual studio.  This is still happening, so clearly some version of this function is still working.  So I thought to try to make it print "Frame Received" 10 times in a row to see if my changes are actually taking effect.  Strangely, even after both building and clean/rebuilding, the program still writes "Frame Received" only once, as if it just ignored my changes.

I'm not sure what is causing this, but as I said it simply appears the my .dll is not being updated and/or visual studio is using an older version of the .dll instead of the newest one.  Either way, I'm not really sure how to fix this.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that earlier, while debugging, I tried to step into one of the functions that I am unable to place breakpoints inside of, and I was hit with this error message:

[image: error]

Comment: It is so weird, that is seems like you're missing something very basic. After rebuilt, does the dll file have the proper creation date? I.e. just now? Are you sure this is the file your application is using? You may have the same dll somewhere in the PATH. Check it with dependency walker.

Comment: old VimbaBridgeAPI.dll somewhere in .dlls search path ? SYSTEM32 etc

Comment: Okay after rebuilding the solution and checking the creation date and time, it says 1 hour ago.  So that means it's not being updated properly I guess.  How do I force it to update the dll again?

Comment: Just delete the old file. It would be hard for it to persist after you've deleted it.

Comment: Well after deleting the old file and rebuilding the solution, it's still not generating another .dll file.  Gaaah

Comment: run TaskManager and check for your program, its looks like you have zombie process which is using your dll and VS just cant overwrite it (.dll i mean)

Comment: @Mikhail No wait!  That was it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably, output of build is going into some to other directory.
-check your outdir setting.